# Keep LocalStorage after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Currently, I enter data, it stores in the local storage and displays it accordingly. Here is the code for that flow:

Creating/Setting Data (in the create.js file)

```
let orders = [];
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'interactive') renderApp();

    function renderApp() {
        var onInit = app.initialized();
        onInit.then(getClient).catch(handleErr);

        function getClient(_client) {
            window.client = _client;
            //client.events.on('app.activated', onAppActivate1);
            onAppActivate1();
        }
    }
};

   function onAppActivate1() {
    
        //intialize an array that will have all the keys user puts in 
        console.log('got here');
        $("#btnCreateOrder").click(function () {
            //orders = localStorage.getItem('orderlist');
            let order = {
                id: Date.now(),
                order: document.getElementById('order').value,
                name: document.getElementById('inputName').value,
                date: document.getElementById('inputDate').value,
                status: document.getElementById('inputStatus').value
            }
            orders.push(order);
            if (!localStorage.getItem('orderlist') || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orderlist')).length === 0) {
                $window.localStorage.setItem('orderlist', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
            }
            //localStorage.setItem('orderlist', JSON.stringify(orders));
            client.instance.send({
                message: {
                    orders: orders
                }
            });
            client.instance.close();
        });
    }
    
    function handleErr(err) {
        console.log('Error Occuered', err);
    }
```

Receiving/Displaying data (app.js)

```
function onAppActivate() {
  //var displayID = new Array();
  console.log("Hi!! We are in the app!");
  client.instance.resize({ height: "350px" });
  client.instance.receive(function (event) {
    var data = event.helper.getData();
    console.log("data is", data);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.message.orders.length; ++i) {
      console.log(data.message.orders.length);
      const orderList = data.message.orders[i];
      console.log("orderlist is ", orderList);
      var order = document.createElement("div");
      order.innerHTML = `<br/> Order#:  ${orderList.order}<br/> Name: ${orderList.name}<br/>
       Date: ${orderList.date}  <br/> Status: ${orderList.status}`;
      order.style.borderBottom = "1px solid black"
      document.getElementById('orderhistory').appendChild(order);
    }
  })
```

when i refresh the app, my data stays but when i reload the browser, the data gets reset but I want the data to stay even if i reload the browser and keep appending to it

Comment: localStorage does not reset unless you explicitly clear it, so as long as your reload your app on the same domain, with the same port, nothing gets wiped. Unless you have code in place that does that, so reduce your code to [mcve] and see if it's still clearing localStorage, because reducing is almost certainly going to let you discover at what point it suddenly stops getting reset.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry i edited my question but basically: 
when i refresh the app, my data stays but when i reload the browser, the data gets reset but I want the data to stay even if i reload the browser and keep appending to it

Comment: What does `$scope.initData` look like?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that your `orders` are being persisted to `localStorage`. it seems that you've commented out the line where you tried it (without JSON-stringification, which could be of issue) I also don't see anywhere that you say `orders = localStorage.getItem("orderList")`. There's just nowhere that you are pulling the information out of localStorage into your app, at least in what you've shown us here.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth well actually im sending the data stored in local storage in create.js and recieving it in app.js.  ```client.instance.send({message: {
orders: orders```